# USB keyboard does not work for Ubuntu boot menu

Tags: ubuntu, boot, keyboard

I wanted to perform a memory test on one of my desktop machines, but encountered a very strange problem: I can use the (usual) USB keyboard (tried Cherry Evolution Stream as well as an older one from Logitech) to open the BIOS (by pressing Del) and changing it, but not in the Ubuntu boot menu (where to select the language and keyboard type for pre-10.* Ubuntu versions). After Ubuntu booted, the keyboard is usable. I've also tried to use a different USB port, but without success.

Is this a known mainboard, BIOS or Ubuntu problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

BIOS. Enable "Legacy USB Keyboard Support".

Comment: There was no such named option in my BIOS, but I've found an option "keyboard support" in a "USB" submenu.