# Phoenix Award BIOS - USB keyboard fails at boot menu

Tags: bios, usb-keyboard

Ok, this is similar to [USB keyboard does not work for Ubuntu boot menu](https://superuser.com/questions/273359/usb-keyboard-does-not-work-for-ubuntu-boot-menu), but not the same.

I have this machine with Phoenix Award bios - BIOS is on , however, boot priority is on . I use a USB keyboard.

The first time, I press F8, go to boot menu, use up and down keys to select USB key - all good, the USB key gets booted.

Then I restart - I press F8, boot menu enters, but I can NO LONGER press the up and down keys (and indeed, ENTER)... So obviously, no booting to usb key this time. Then I plug in a PS/2 keyboard - works no problem, can boot...

WTF?! If USB keyboard doesn't work - then how the hell did I boot the first time using the USB keyboard ???!!

Can anyone explain this? Is it possible the BIOS got corrupted or something (it is not the newest computer, this...)?

Thanks in advance,
Cheers!

EDIT: Note that the second time, I pressed  on the USB keyboard, and BIOS registered it, went into boot menu, and then stopped registering... Even stupider is, I just now plugged in a PS/2 keyboard in parallel with the USB one - and the USB one now started working ??!! Ah never mind, at least I can boot - but I'm really curious why would this happen.. PS: Also - there is no "Legacy USB keyboard" option in this BIOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had this problem on some older motherboards. The solution was to use another USB port. Keyboard simply didn't work on some of them.

Comment: Thanks for that @HenryHeikkinen - I will try that, and accept the answer after I've verified... Cheers!

Comment: Sorry for the delay in accept @HenryHeikkinen (strangely, my problem disappeared after you posted your answer - so I never got to verify it `:)` ) - Cheers!