# Unable to enter bios in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, bios

I was trying to find out why my USB keyboard didn't work during the Ubuntu dual boot screen. From this question [USB keyboard does not work for Ubuntu boot menu](https://superuser.com/questions/273359/usb-keyboard-does-not-work-for-ubuntu-boot-menu) I know that this is a problem I can probably resolve in my machine's BIOS. However, I am unable to enter it (I have tried pushing every button, tried every USB port on my computer, and I have a "regular" USB keyboard).

I reversed the order of Ubuntu and Windows (dual boot) and put Ubuntu as first. Since then, my motherboard's logo no longer appears, in which I was able to enter the BIOS. Now I am taken straight to the Ubuntu boot screen (where I can choose between ubuntu and windows -- if my keyboard worked!)

What can I do in this situation? I'm planning to buy a USB-to-PS2 converter for keyboard.

Comment: Normally a USB Keyboard should work. Shut down Ubuntu and make sure OFF (not suspend or something). Shut down Windows and make sure OFF (not suspended or like).  Make sure everything is off. Start up and press F1 repeatedly and see if it starts in BIOS. F1 is reasonably standard.

Answer (score 1):

While it sounds like a minor nuisance, there are other ways to get to BIOS other than from the grub menu, e.g. during startup.

- Shut down the PC **completely**.

  - In Windows, make sure Fast Startup is *off*. Press <kbd>Windows</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, type `shutdown /s /t 0` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
  - In Ubuntu, perform a full shutdown, not sleep.
- **Hold down** the **correct** function key **for your model PC**. If you do not know this, look it up online; "pushing every button" will *not* work.
- With the correct function key held down, press the power button. Keep holding the function key (do not press repeatedly) until the BIOS menu shows.

Another way to force complete shutdown is to hold the power button for about ten seconds. This *abruptly* shuts the PC without gracefully completing writes to the SSD/HDD, and is not recommended.